# Many to many relationship in the same table?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, many-to-many

I'm relatively new to designing a database, and I'm wondering what the canonical way to implement a many to many relationship between rows in the same table is.

In my case I have a table of formulas and I want to say that two formulas in the table are related:

The formulas table:

```
formula_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
name TEXT NOT NULL
formula TEXT NOT NULL
```

I assume I would make a new table called related_formulas and then do something like:

```
formula_relation_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
formula_id INT REFERENCES formulas (formula_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
formula_id2 INT REFERENCES formulas (formula_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

but then I foresee problems such as preventing two ids in the same row from having the same value. I'm sure there are also other potential problems that I don't see due to my own inexperience.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How about setting both formula_id and formula as primary keys and use the same formula_id for related formulas?

Comment: It would work if the relationship is an equivalence, so all members of an equivalence class share an identifier; but the relation is not necessarily an equivalence. For example, "related to" does not have to be transitive: If `i` is related to `A[i]` and `A[i]` related to `A`, `i` is not necessarily related to `A`.

Comment: Why couldn't two ids in the same row have same value? Or are you saying they could but shouldn't, and you don't know how to prevent it?

Comment: @Amadan "Or are you saying they could but shouldn't, and you don't know how to prevent it" yeah that's what I'm saying. A formula shouldn't reference itself. Also how would I structure it if I was to take into consideration what you said about how related to isn't necessarily equivalence.

Comment: A *table* expresses a relationship. A REFERENCES expresses a constraint, ie a fact about 2 tables, ie a fact about their 2 relationships, not a relationship. Instead of just talking about "the relationship" *say what it is*. So table formula holds rows where "*formula_id* identifies formula *formula* which is named *name*" with the other table maybe being is_the_A_of holding rows where "formula *formula_idA* is A[*formula_id*]". (Or is_in_the equivalence_class_of?) Then is_the_A_of (ie A) is "the relationship" (which is not transitive, is symmetric, etc).

Comment: Look up data structures for bill of materials (BOM) processing.  A unction table is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `SERIAL` I assumed PostgreSQL...

```
CREATE TABLE formula_relation (
  formula_relation_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  formula1_id INT REFERENCES formulas (formula_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  formula2_id INT REFERENCES formulas (formula_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CHECK (formula1_id < formula2_id)
);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dcaeb)

(I also assumed that your relation is symmetric, so `i` being related to `A[i]` also implies `A[i]` is related to `i`; thus, having `formula1_id < formula2_id` ensures there can only be one, canonical, variant of the row, and you don't need to check for the reverse pairing. If the relation is not symmetric, you should just `CHECK (formula1_id != formula2_id)`.)

Answer (score 1):

Amadan's answer is good to ensure the data is inserted in one canonical way, however if you prefer not to restrict your db users to a specific order when inserting the formulas (which was imposed by `CHECK (formula1_id < formula2_id)` in Amadan's answer), you can consider:

```sql
CREATE TABLE formula (
    id int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    formula_name text NOT NULL,
    formula text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE formula_formula_relation (
    id int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    formula1_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES formula ON DELETE CASCADE,
    formula2_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES formula ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CHECK (formula1_id <> formula2_id),
    CONSTRAINT already_related_formulas_not_allowed_again EXCLUDE USING gist (
        LEAST    (formula1_id, formula2_id) WITH =,
        GREATEST (formula1_id, formula2_id) WITH =
    )
);
```

(You might need to run `CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;`)